# my node code is in a loading loop when I enter the host location

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm doing a node course and I got to the beginning of a project, however when trying to enter the host location and at the defined port the application just stays in a loading loop and doesn't load

APP.JS

```
// Módulos
    const express = require('express');
    const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
    const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express() 
    const admin = require('./routes/admin.js');
    // const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Config
    // Body Parser
        app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
        app.use(bodyparser.json);
    //Handlebars
        app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaltLayout: 'main'}));
        app.set('view engine','handlebars');
    //Mongoose

//Rotas  
    app.use('/admin',admin);

//Outros
const PORT = 8081;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Servidor Rodando');
})
```

ADMIN.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('Pagina principal, painel de adm')
})
router.get('/posts', (req,res) => {
     res.send('Pagina de posts');
})
router.get('/categorias',(req,res) => {
    res.send('Pagina de categorias');
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?
Is the webpage in a browser not loading?
What url are you accessing?
Can you include the console output when you run the node server?

Comment: When running the script on it works normally and the output of "server running" is printed, however when trying to enter localhost: 8081 the page is just loading and does not return, all routes are defined in the admim.js file in the routes folder , but when trying to connect it just keeps loading and doesn't finish loading the page

Comment: I think you are going to the wrong URL, can you try `http://localhost:8081/admin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the error, follow the code
APP.JS

```
// Módulos
    const express = require('express');
    const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
    const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express();
    const admin = require("./routes/admin.js");
    // const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Config
    // Body Parser
        app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
        app.use(bodyparser.json());
    //Handlebars
        app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
        app.set('view engine','handlebars');
    //Mongoose
//Rotas  
    app.use('/admin', admin);
//Outros
const PORT = 8081;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Servidor Rodando');
})
```

ADMIN.JS

```
const express= require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send("Pagina principal do painel ADM");
})
router.get('/posts', (req,res) => {
    res.send("Pagina de posts");
})
router.get('/categorias', (req,res) => {
    res.send("Pagina de categorias");
})


module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to visit the root URL i.e. `http://localhost:8081/` then you have to write the code for handle that route currently your code handle just `http://localhost:8081/admin/*` routes so if it is a mistake then create a route for the root.

in the App.js file -

APP.JS

```
// Módulos
    const express = require('express');
    const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
    const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
    const app = express() 
    const admin = require('./routes/admin.js');
    // const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Config
    // Body Parser
        app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
        app.use(bodyparser.json());
    //Handlebars
        app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaltLayout: 'main'}));
        app.set('view engine','handlebars');
    //Mongoose
    
    //Rotas
//here is the code to handle the root route
    
    app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
        res.send("this is the homepage");
    });  
    app.use('/admin',admin);

//Outros
const PORT = 8081;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Servidor Rodando');
})
```

Comment: All routes are defined in the admin.js file

Comment: @EntonyMaxwell when you are using app.use('/admin', admin); meaning of this line is that all the requests starting with localhost:port/admin will go to your route inside admin.js so if you are using app.get('/', callback) inside your admin.js meaning of that is it will handle every request with localhost:port/admin/ not localhost:port/